# In WP, Google map error initMap is not a function

Tags: pages, google-maps

Getting a series of errors on some Goole maps JS, that will show a series of markers from a json file as well as showing the list.    The map comes up and works with all the markers and info windows opening, but the list doesn't open markers.   I'm getting a series of errors as well in WordPress.  I call the google map api in the functions file y=using enque.  In a straight html, the page works fine with no errors.

The first error I'm getting is:

"initMap is not a function"
name
:
"InvalidValueError"
stack
:
"Error↵    at new kc (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-API-KEYk&callback=initMap&ver=4.7.4:47:499)↵    at Object._.lc 
**proto**
:
Error

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var arrMarkers = [];
        var arrInfoWindows = [];

        function mapInit(){
            var centerCoord = new google.maps.LatLng(48.058249, -122.288615);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 12,
                center: centerCoord,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
            $.getJSON("/wp-content/themes/the-language-of-puget-sound/js/map12.json", {}, function(data){
                $.each(data.places, function(i, item){
                $("#markers").append('<li><a href="#" rel="' + i + '">' + item.English_Name + '</a></li>');
                var image = '/wp-content/themes/the-language-of-puget-sound/js/Marker5-50.png';
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                     position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.Y_DD, item.X_DD),
                     map: map,
                     icon: image,
                     title: item.English_Name
                     });
                     arrMarkers[i] = marker;
                     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: "<span style='font-family: 
                        LushootseedSulad; font-size: large;'>"+ item.Lushootseed +"</span><br><b>English Name: "+ item.English_Name +"</b><br>Meaning: "+ item.Meaning +"<br><img src="+ item.image +"><br>"+ item.Description +"<br><span style='font-family: LushootseedSulad; font-size: medium;'>"+ item.Lushootseed +"</span><br><audio controls='true' preload='none' style='width:200px'><br><source src='/wp-content/uploads/places/"+ item.audio +"'' type='audio/mpeg'/>", border: 4, maxWidth: 250,
            });
            arrInfoWindows[i] = infowindow;
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            var i = $(this).attr("rel");
            // this next line closes all open infowindows before opening the selected one
            for(x=0; x < arrInfoWindows.length; x++){ arrInfoWindows[x].close(); }  
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
               });
           });
        }
        $(function(){
        // initialize map (create markers, infowindows and list)
    mapInit();

        // "live" bind click event
        $("#markers a").live("click", function(){
             var i = $(this).attr("rel");
        // this next line closes all open infowindows before opening the selected one
        for(x=0; x < arrInfoWindows.length; x++){ arrInfoWindows[x].close(); 
    }
    arrInfoWindows[i].open(map, arrMarkers[i]);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-API-KEYk&**callback=initMap**&ver=4.7.4:47:499

This api request requires an existing callback. Rename your function from `mapInit` to `initMap` and it will work (unless your function is invalid).

Comment: That worked perfectly to remove that error.  I had thought about changing it before but felt it would change anything since it was working fine in straight html/js.

Comment: So on to the next error, --  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function So I' guessing the first I initMap was not done globally.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated and removed since jQuery 1.9 (http://api.jquery.com/live/). use `.on('click', function() { … })`.

Comment: Perfecto!  works great Only warnings I get now are some about warnings about upcoming depreciation in Chrome about zoom, but I don't see any code in my css about that.

Comment: use your console and look for the origin of the warning. it’s probably not in your css files.

Comment: Not sure if you have time, something went terribly wrong getting a lot of errors again and markers aren't showing up.   The info windows stopped functioning properly.  I tried to restore files from a backup but chose the wrong date.

Comment: dsienko@ tuleliptribes-nsn.gov

Comment: I’m not a faith healer. I need error messages from your console, and/or your code. an please don’t post your email address. let’s use this feed to keep your issue well documented for other people.

Comment: Great  Thanks,   So to start here's how I'm inserting the google-maps api in wordpress

Comment: Great  Thanks,   So to start here's how I'm inserting the google-maps api in wordpress   wp_enqueue_script( 'google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY API KEY&callback=initMap&ver=4.7.4:74:499', array(), '', true );  Then here's the jquery string  in the footer <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>   Then the script I'm using, which is inserted into the WP page via CSS/JS Toolbox   is the same as above with the two corrections you noted.  Now the first error I'm getting is  Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function .

Comment: Here's the next error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getJSON' of undefined
    at initMap    There's a string of errors after this, as well.  The first one seems to be related to jquery and WP.

Comment: the main problem is, that – as your error message told us – $ is not a function. $ should be an alias of jQuery. WordPress do not provide $ because there are many other frameworks which use $ – there would be a conflict. To put it in a nutshell, replace `$.` with `jQuery.`. This should fix many of your errors.

Comment: That seemed to work I replaced $, with jQuery. and $ with jQuery  , so hopefully it will continue to work.   I got frustrated last week when it was working, but later the next morning it stopped working.  I hate cache at times.   Thanks for your help.